# Как правильнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать: "вред чего-то" (например, "вред курения") или "вред от чего-то" ("вред от курения"). Или тут разный смысл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможны словосочетания "**вред чего-либо**" (например, *лекция о вреде курения*) и "**вред от чего-либо**" (например, *вред от излишеств, от перегрузок*). На мой взгляд, некоторая разница в семантике есть. В первом случае имеется в виду *вредность, вредные стороны* чего-либо. Во втором случае видится *нанесенный ущерб*. Возможно, у кого-то будут иные соображения.